# Crystal Report - Avoid Paramet Prompt box When Progrmme Running

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm Try to implement Crystal report in .Net C# Windows forms. When Run crystal report through the project Parameter prompt box asking parameters. All the parameters are set by dynamically in C#.

Code:

```
                ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

                rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt1);                    

                rptDoc.Load("ChequePrint.rpt");
                rptDoc.SetParameterValue(0, trnKy);

                // Set Data Base Connection
                rptDoc = this.SetCrystalConnection(rptDoc);

                // Pass Report Document to Crystal Viewer form                    
                frmCrystalReportViewer crystalViewFrm = new frmCrystalReportViewer();
                crystalViewFrm.loadReport(rptDoc);
                crystalViewFrm.Show();
```

Crystal Viewver Form :

```
               try
        {
            rptDoc.Refresh();
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;

            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }
```

Comment: May I ask the order of your parameters and what data types they are?

Comment: It's only one parameter. Data Type is long